# Should I change college to have a better undergraduate foundation?

Tags: university, academic-life, industry, age, electrical-engineering

I am 21 and I study Electronics Engineering. I am at the end of my third year, and I realised where I wanted to put my focus in my graduate studies. What fascinated me the most about EE is the physics behind it, from mechanics to electromagnetics waves. The problem is that my university has absolutely no research on any of the EE fields that are close to physics: Photonics, Semiconductor devices or Electromagnetic Engineering. The focus of my university lies in programming and practical skills, rather than theory, and that worries me, because the field I want to specialize in require a good level of understanding and and really solid math skills. To put you in perspective the physics background that my universities offers is: 1 course in Mechanics, 1 course in Electromagnetism (with no vector calculus as a prerequisite...) and Electromagnetic Waves (the only challenging physics course I have taken and I absolutely loved). So no Semiconductor Physics, no Electromagnetism with vector calculus, and no optional courses on Optoelectronics, Fiber Optics or Laser Physics. That's why I am really worried about my career and considering changing universities. My questions or doubts are the following:

1. Supposing I would have to start EE somewhere else from start, I will be graduating with a BSc degree at age 24.5 or 25.5. Is this problematic to enter the industry or academia when I graduate?
   I know that some people start later in life, but in general they gained work experience before, while I haven't (I worked as a TA in the Math department of my university but I don't know if that really counts as real world work experience).
2. Is it necessary to change university, or can I catch up my deficiencies later when I go to grad school? I think I can but it is not ideal. A part from that, it would be difficult to pursue a masters or a phd in something I would not be having any experience on, besides from learning on my own of course (which is not the same as being guided by world class professors).

Consider that I am currently in a university where the electronics degree takes 5 years (it has a theoretical thesis at the end), so I will be graduating with the degree at 23 years old. Next year I have the chance to go to EPFL (very highly rated engineering school in Switzerland) where the bachelor takes 3 years and the path to the masters is direct. However, it is with the masters that you become a qualified "Engineer".
My other path option is to go to UOttawa in Canada. This university is not as good as EPFL (this is just based on ranking of course, real life is different) but it still is an amazing university and MUCH better than the one I'm currently in.

To finalise I would like to be clear with what my goals are. I am passionate about learning as much as I can about Electrical Engineering, and want to specialize in Applied Physics of EE as I mentioned before, although I do not know in what particular subfield exactly. When I get my masters degree I don't know if I would go straight into industry or do a PhD, but my dream would be to do both!

Comment: Too personal for a good answer here. But I don't see any age issues. Maybe if you were 81, but not 21.